# Function of retval in pthread_join

Tags: c, operating-system, pthreads

I'm learning threading in C in OS. I don't know why following code is giving me segmentation fault. Can anyone help me here? I am also confused a bit about how `pthread_join` uses its argument `void ** retval`. What is its function?

```
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

void *thread (void *vargp) {
   int* arg = *((int*)vargp);
   return (void*)arg;
}   

int main () {
   pthread_t tid;
   int thread_arg = 0xDEADBEEF;
   int *ret_value;
   pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread, &thread_arg);
   pthread_join(tid, (void **)(&ret_value));
   printf("%X\n", *ret_value);
   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: The thread is supposed to call `pthread_exit()` to pass the return value.

Comment: @Barmar You can also return it from the thread function.

Comment: ... which is, after all, why the required signature of the thread function declartes that it returns `void *`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not correct:

```
int* arg = *((int*)vargp);
```

`(int*)vargp` cast your `void*` to `int*`. But by writing `int* arg = *((int*)vargp);` you assing to the `arg` pointer the VALUE (0xDEADBEEF) of the argument `vargp`. This value (0xDEADBEEF) is not a valid adress.
what is the version of your compiler? because he must alert you :

*invalid conversion from `int` to `int*`*

You should write:

```
int* arg = (int*) vargp;
```

Comment: In addition, this is UB: `pthread_join(tid, (void **)(&ret_value));`. `ret_value` needs to have type `void *`, and then you just pass `&ret_value`. After `pthread_join` returns, you can convert `ret_value` to `int *` or whatever pointer type is appropriate via an assignment/cast/whatever.